# How to transfer information to the development team?

Tags: workflow, interface-design, front-end-development

I am a UI team lead.

I detected that the topic of "how do you want the graphics?" is a very hot topic in my company. And I find myself always giving the same explanation.

I would like to give like a "checklist" for the PMs and the designers we work with to make the work more efficient and fun.

Currently there's this constant ping-pong in emails between us and PMs. I would like to get rid of that..

Thought about the following list (several of the items I gathered so far..):

- The design should be web and mobile friendly. (yes - sometimes we get some crazy design that require us to use mostly images even with all the power of CSS today..)
- Flat design is good. - obviously a recommendation.
- Images should have transparent background.
- Formats:

  - The original PSD file
  - Each layer in PNG with transparent background.
  - Icons and flat images should be in SVG, and if possible - as a font. (we usually convert to font ourselves).
- General guideline of the design should be attached.

  - color palette and the purpose for each color: Title, subtitle, text, disabled items, actions items.. etc..
  - important alignments guidelines - sometimes we miss the need for things to align whereas the designer feels they based the entire design on that. This usually affects the HTML structure as well - so it is very important to have common grounds on this ASAP.
  - Error messages display (ALWAYS MISSING! no one designs the errors..)

And then a whole different section for emails :P

We usually develop web design, but non-web might be required too in the future.

Seems to me like someone probably already made such a list and I am reinventing the wheel.

What is the standard for passing the grail from the designer to the dev team?

## Edit

This question is technical.

What is the standard way of getting deliveries from the designer?

or if you'd like - as a designer - what is my checklist for delivery?

I assume almost every HiTech company with GUI has this process, so it must have grown into a written standard I can simply send to my designers, and make sure they follow it.

Like a checklist the designers will check, and my team will validate to avoid back and forth correspondence like "we need this in png" , "can you also get jpg?" etc.. which consumes a lot of time, and is just not right as I want to allow the designers to move forward and forget this project.

Especially since the design step happens way before the implementation, and by the time we reach that phase, we start to discover we are missing some artifacts from the designer.

I expect people to publish their checklist, or reference me to a checklist they are using.

The first answer that hits the spot will be accepted. Opinions like "whether this checklist or that checklist is better" has no room here.

If there is no such standard checklist, I think there should be, and I also think this question has a great potential to start one right here.

The workflow is known, the motivation is very high, the communication between us and the designer is great. This part of the process is understood, but the content is always questioned, and I can't understand why.

Comment: We have several questions on this topic.  Search for [design collaboration](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/search?q=design+collaboration).  If none of those work please edit your question with more detail.

Comment: @Matt - Sorry, but I'm not finding another question relating to this. The one this is marked as a "duplicate" of has nothing to do with the topic of this question. This is a problem that comes up a lot, and I would love to know more about how others deal with these issues.

Comment: Are you not asking us to help you establish a workflow and a collaboration between your team and the PM's?  The question marked as a duplicate because you seem to want collaboration but make it fun.  You could even reference several other questions similar under the [tag:workflow]

Comment: I would agree that there are a number of questions addressing workflow between design and UI developers, but I haven't found one that's actually a duplicate of this -- asking for a list or set of guidelines on how to provide design assets.

Comment: If he is wanting a list some would argue its an opionated answer.  How can someone provide an answer to his question on what exactly to do?  Everyone has a different workflow and i dont mind the question but when you read it do you not agree there will be all opinions on how to define a workflow and wouldn't the many questions we have on designer and client relations fall around those guidlines with the only difference is a designer to a developer?

Comment: @Matt. I cannot control how people answer but only down vote them. Every question can have an opinion. Even "how to resolve this null pointer exception" which is clearly technical and acceptable could have answers like "I think this is better.." answers. 

I still need some guidance as to how to tackle the issue. This is a process that exists in almost every HiTech company, it must have a standard by now, no? I am looking for that standard. like "how to write a loop in javascript?" - so how to get delivery from designer. same thing for me.

Comment: @Matt made an edit on the question as you requested.

Comment: What I meant is `if you are a designer, and you prefer to have the question phrased differently then it would be..` I didn't mean to imply I am a designer.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something that I've found very useful in the past:
http://photoshopetiquette.com/

It doesn't answer every part of your question, but I find that it covers the majority of the issues I commonly encounter when receiving Photoshop files from designers. Things like labeling layers, using layer comps, including fonts, avoiding multiply and other blend modes that CSS doesn't support (yet!), just general stuff that makes a front-end developer's life easier.

Comment: Thanks for commenting! Could you please include some from the article so that your answer doesn't become useless if the linked site goes down?

Comment: This is indeed a good start but it seems like more a guide on how to design properly, rather than how to pass along the design to the development team properly - which is what I am interested about.

Comment: Fixed. And this is definitely not a duplicate of "How to guide the workflow in a collaboration? How to not kill the other’s motivation?" That question has no relation to the topic being discussed here.